# Размер массива

Tags: память, c++

Учу сейчас c++, такой вопрос: если я пишу

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];

    return 0;
}
```

какого размера будет массив: n или 2^32-1?

Comment: - Откуда вы взяли `2^32 - 1,` честно говоря, непонятно.

- По стандарту в `C++` `Variable Length Arrays` запрещены (см. `8.3.4.1`)`.`

- Есть компиляторы, которые поддерживают их как `extension'ы`, см. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151254/wheres-gs-vla-extension**

- Соответственно, в зависимости от используемого компилятора вы получите либо ошибку компиляции, либо зааллоченный массив размера `n.`

Comment: @Котик: почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD Ну я опоздал, пока искал референс в стандарте, и там уже ответили правильно `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему ему быть 2^32 -1 ? Он будет ровно сколько, сколько введете. Другое дело, что это не совсем стандартное расширение С++. В gcc это будет работать, по поводу других компиляторов не знаю.

Comment: @KoVadim: причём размер не в смысле sizeof, а в смысле количества элементов, как и показывает ваш пример. (Т.к. sizeof -- константа времени компиляции.)

Answer (score 2):

> если я пишу

а почему бы вам не попробовать и не написать это и увидеть, что эта ваша чушь даже не скомпилируется, так как размер массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции?

З.Ы. раз уж меня авторитетно поправили ([[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), спасибо), то добавлю, что если какие-то компиляторы это съедят (чесслово, сюрприз), то чтобы проверить размер массива, можете сделать sizeof(a)

З.З.Ы. Стыдоба-то какая

Comment: смотря от компилятора, может и [скомпилироваться](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2k041o$0).

g++ (4.7) ([пруф](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) спокойно это компилирует. clang также. А интелловский компилятор даже не ругается.

sizeof покажет размер в байтах, нужно будет ещё разделить на размер элемента.

Comment: @DreamChild: это нестандартное расширение у gcc, работает так же, как и [alloca](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/alloca.3.html).